# SVG Background Image Tiling for Printing

Tags: css, svg, background-image

If I use a SVG tile as the background for a site, it looks fine when viewed in browser but, if printed, scales in a weird nonuniform way. Is there a way to have the browser print without distortion

An example of this is [here](https://jzl.github.io/WeeklyCalendar/dots.html), it looks like this:

[image]

But on printing looks like this:

[image]

```
 <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'>
<rect width='10' height='10' fill='#fff'/>
<rect width='5' height='5' fill='#ccc'/>
</svg>
```

```css
#test {
  height: 500px;
  width:500px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMCI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIxMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMCIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiI+PC9yZWN0Pgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1IiBmaWxsPSIjY2NjIj48L3JlY3Q+Cjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

The SVG is from

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug, works fine on FF. You should open a bug on their bug tracker.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **svg** in **img** tag and append via jquery like below snippet I hope helps and It is working fine for **print** on **Chrome** and **FF** browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var squareBox = 3000; //You can increase and descrease of square boxes
 for (var i = 1; i <= squareBox; i++) {
  $('#test').append('<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMCI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIxMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMCIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiI+PC9yZWN0Pgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1IiBmaWxsPSIjY2NjIj48L3JlY3Q+Cjwvc3ZnPg==">');
 }
})
```

```css
#test{
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#test img{
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
@media print and (color){
*{
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  print-color-adjust: exact;
}
button{display: none;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Seriously ? replace a background-repeat with a ton of img tags ?

Comment: Yes, Because of when I am try to your code as background by css and print then this is not proper appear on chrome in print view. So if you repeat multiple same image via for loop. I think your print problem will solve.

Comment: This is not mine, I'm not OP, but doing this you'll more than likely create a lot of memory issues...

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry, Yes you are right  for lot of memory issues. I am just passing my idea that we can use like this also.